# How to make multiple selection filter in views in drupal 7?

Tags: views

I am using drupal-7. I have created a views with expose filter with multiple selection .. I have 3 fields in expose (small,medium and large) its working fine.
when I select small its give small related data..
Note: But I need when I clicked on small then I need to small data and if i checked medium then I need both data Means small and medium.

Comment: are you using small, medium and large as taxonomy terms?

Comment: no.. I created a text field .

Comment: I have a range text filed in content type. here filling small medium and large

Comment: use facet with search api it will solve your issue

Comment: Its a search related module. But I need multiple selection filter. :(